# AgilityPack - Maintaining a 'connection' for several HTTP Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-agility-pack

I have a system that needs to make several calls to an API as a single 'job'. 
I connect to a proxy via a hostname to carry out the job so it doesn't assign me an IP address I can see. I essentially hand over the task.

At the moment I'm using HtmlWeb to make the call to my URL list like so:

```
var webProxy = new WebProxy(Address: [MyProxyHost]);

var web = new HtmlWeb();
web.UseCookies = false;
web.UserAgent = "[MyUserAgent]";
var htmlDoc = web.Load("[URL]","GET", webProxy, webCreds);
//...do stuff with results...
```

The problem: as it stands, every request I make will rotate the proxy (as every 'call' using the proxy host randomly changes the IP their side - I have no control over this).

What I want to be able to do is re-use the http request/connection over several calls (I appreciate I probably won't be able to use HtmlWeb for this).

So I would essentially say:

- Create HTTP Request Object (w/ Proxy host)
- Open/Initialize
- Make Request 1
- ...
- Make Request N
- Close & Dispose

Is this possible?

Comment: .. use an HttpClient to download the HTML?

Comment: I'm looking at this now. I'm using a `WebProxy` with a `HttpClientHandler` for a `HttpClient` across the several calls. I will update with how I get on

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got the following in place and *so far* it seems to be ok:

```
var webProxy = new WebProxy()
{
    Address = new Uri([ServerHost] + ":" + [ServerPort]),
    BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
        userName: [Username],
        password: [Password])
};

var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Proxy = webProxy,
};

var _httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
...
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync([Url]);
var pageContents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var htmlDoc.LoadHtml(pageContents);
...
```

This makes the request to each URL using the proxy and converts the page returned to a `HtmlDocument` so I can do the AgilityPack stuff I need to.